# (How) can I save my components after ESD accident?

Tags: esd, damage

In winter time I am often charged with electricity and frequently encounter esd during the days. I know I should have esd protection when working with electric components, but now it is too late:

I have [this display](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1947) and [this board.](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah32-esp32-feather) Both where connected with each other and with my Laptop via USB. When I touched the display I heard a "zap" and it immediately went black. The board is still blinking though. I tried powering the display with another controller, but it will not light up anymore. This is why I am pretty sure I damaged it with esd.

My question is, would it be possible to rescue the display? What tools do I need (I guess something like multimeter or oscilloscope)? Does it make sense to try to measure each resistor and capacitor on the board to find the (in my naive thinking one and only) broken one and replace it? Or is it likely that I have to throw it all away? As the display costs nearly 50$ and I had to wait an eternity for it to arrive I really want to save the one I have...

Answer (score 4):

Most likely it is toast. The damage is probably to an IC in which case you would have to identify which one, find a replacement part and then replace it on the board.